# wifi not working with ethernet while vpn connect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, ethernet, wifi-configuration

I have two connections in my pc , one is wifi and another is ethernet , each of which are connected, when I connect to vpn , ethernet remains connected but wifi becomes "no internet" ..why is that and how to fix it to keep both connected while vpn connected?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft PPPtP VPN or VPN without Split Tunnel?

Comment: What OS is on the system?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 and vpn with pptp connection

Comment: That is precisely why you are losing the outside connection.

Comment: Why are you connected to both connections? Which connection is the VPN supposed to be using? Is this an enterprise VPN, or a personal system/product? Is one of the connections for local network resources? Please edit your question to add the requested info and make your question more clear.

Comment: I make idm (internet download manager) restricted to wifi ip address using ForceBindIP.exe ..so while I'm browsing using ethernet connection, idm keeps downloading using wifi connection ;to get full speed for both connections ;but when I connect to vpn software , ethernet remains with internet and wifi still connected but no internet , so idm stops downloading !!